# Extracting probabilities from a weighted selection process

Tags: probability

Apologies for my bad/basic mathematical notation.

There is a set of options $O = \{o_1, ... o_n\}$,

There are ${n \choose 2}$ unique combinations of pairs that can be selected from the set O

We have a selection process where we are given the probabilities of selecting a particular pair as $P = \{P_{ij}\}$  where $P_{ij}$ is the probability of selection the unique pair $[O_iO_j]$ where:

1. $i < j$,
2. $\sum P_{ij}$ = $1$
3. $|P| = {n \choose 2}$

**Question:** If a random pair were to be selected what is the probability that $O_i$ is one of the options in the pair?

**Question II:** Is there enough information to solve this problem or is it ill defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum_{j\lt i}P_{ji}+\sum_{j\gt i}P_{ij}$$

Comment: aaah, thats what i was missing! thanks.